# Opened port but have Node.js listen on it?

Tags: apache2

I am using Digital Ocean as a host and I have set Apache to listen to port 3000 however I would like to run a node.js instance on it. If I try starting my node.js app it says Port is already in use. Which is my problem: if I don't allow Apache to listen on port 3000 and start the node.js app, I get a 'connection unexpectedly closed' error. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4):

You can't have two services listening at the same port.

Solution: Change your `nodejs` app port or your `apache` port.

If you change your `apache` port you will need restart the service (`service apache2 restart`).